# GmailSettingsService not found

Tags: java, google-email-settings-api

I am creating a java app for Google admin tasks and have successfully accessed a few bits using various Google APIs.  However I am having trouble with the "[Google Apps Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/)"

The sample code given for Java shows the import as:-

```
import sample.appsforyourdomain.gmailsettings.GmailSettingsService;
```

which I can't seem to find in the gdata libraries.  Closest I can get is:-

```
import com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.gmailsettings.GmailFilterService;
```

But with this when I am trying to create the GmailSettingsService as per the sample code:-

```
GmailSettingsService service = new GmailSettingsService....
```

it is not found.  Please help, I am sure it's something simple/stupid I have missed!

Thanks
Phil

Comment: you want to send email using gmail id ?...or?

Comment: The first thing I was trying to get it to do was to display a list of delegates for a particular mailbox - sample code was given as:-                            import sample.appsforyourdomain.gmailsettings.GmailSettingsService;
...

GmailSettingsService service = new GmailSettingsService("your-apps", "example.com", "adminUsername", "adminPassword");
service.retrieveEmailDelegates("user");

Comment: Check this documentation, it may help: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/appsforyourdomain/gmailsettings/GmailSettingsService.java?r=499

Answer (score 1):

You should download servlet-api-2.4.jar (included in Sun's Servlet API - version 2.3 or greater), mail.jar (included in Sun's JavaMail API - version 1.4 or greater) and activation.jar (included in Sun's JavaBeans Activation Framework).

Then update build.properties file (in /gdata-client-java-master/java/build-samples/) with proper path values pointed to that jars.
Then run command "`ant -f build-samples.xml sample.appsforyourdomain.run`" from /gdata-client-java-master/java.

If operation completed successfully AppsForYourDomainClient.jar will be available in /gdata-client-java-master/java/sample/appsforyourdomain/lib/. After adding this jar to your classpath you will be able to use GmailSettingsService.